# How to align text into two columns within LI?

Tags: html, css, list, text, html-lists

So I have this basic unordered list with 5 list and I want some help on how to make the text in each list to align in two segment that look like this:

- Topic 1            (definition)
- Topic 2            (definition)
- Topic 3            (definition)
- Topic 4            (definition)
- Topic 5            (definition)

Where the (definition) have a huge space between the Topic so that it will look like a two column list.

Comment: Please give a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for a [description list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) combined with a [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

```css
dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
dt {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: disc;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<dl>

  <dt>Topic 1</dt>
  <dd>(definition)</dd>

  <dt>Topic 2</dt>
  <dd>(definition)</dd>

  <dt>Topic 3</dt>
  <dd>(definition)</dd>

  <dt>Topic 4</dt>
  <dd>(definition)</dd>

  <dt>Topic 5</dt>
  <dd>(definition)</dd>

</dl>
```